# Retrofit 2 return List from Json is empty

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

I have been fighting with **Retrofit 2.3 for** about 2 weeks now. The List always comes back as empty for me. It simply makes a call and gets the JSON information yet it won't process the list.

Json appears like this:

```
{
"users": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Users Name",
        "username": "myusername",
        "facebook_id": null,
        "level": "1",
        "birthdate": "1999-09-09T00:00:00+00:00",
        "email": "user@gmail.com",
        "activated": "",
        "created": "2017-12-07T04:18:30+00:00",
        "answers": [
            {
                "id": 31,
                "question_id": 2,
                "user_id": 2,
                "answer": "School",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "question": "Where did you meet your best friend?"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 32,
                "question_id": 3,
                "user_id": 2,
                "answer": "Dog",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "question": "What was your first pet's name?"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"message": "Success"
}
```

Retrofit Interface class:

```
public interface RestInterface {

String url = "http://myurl.com";

/**
 * Login
 *
 * @param username  Username
 * @param password  Password
 *
 */

@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers("User-Agent:My-Application")
@POST("login")
Call<userlogin> Login(@Field("username") String username,
                      @Field("password") String password);
}
```

Userlogin class:

```
public class userlogin {

@SerializedName("users")
@Expose
private List<users> users;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private Object message;

public List<users> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<users> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

public Object getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(Object message) {
    this.message = message;
}

}
```

users class:

```
public class users {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("facebook_id")
    @Expose
    private String facebookId;
    @SerializedName("level")
    @Expose
    private String level;
    @SerializedName("birthdate")
    @Expose
    private String birthdate;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("activated")
    @Expose
    private String activated;
    @SerializedName("created")
    @Expose
    private String created;


    @SerializedName("answers")
    @Expose
    private List<Answer> answers = null;

    public users(){

    }

    public Integer getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
            return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
            return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFacebookId() {
            return facebookId;
    }

    public void setFacebookId(String facebookId) {
            this.facebookId = facebookId;
    }

    public String getLevel() {
            return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(String level) {
            this.level = level;
    }

    public String getBirthdate() {
            return birthdate;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(String birthdate) {
            this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
            return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
    }

    public String getActivated() {
            return activated;
    }

    public void setActivated(String activated) {
            this.activated = activated;
    }

    public String getCreated() {
            return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(String created) {
            this.created = created;
    }

    public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
            return answers;
    }

    public void setAnswers(List<Answer> answers) {
            this.answers = answers;
    }

}
```

Basically what happens is when it is called my "message" part comes back "Successful" which on my PHP side basically just states there were no errors. If there were any then it would return the error for display.

When trying to get the users information it always comes back with an empty List.

My response is always the same:
03-14 20:06:26.698 30995-30995/com.josh.testapp D/Response: {"message":"Success","users":[]}

03-14 20:06:26.699 30995-30995/com.josh.testapp I/System.out: Users:: []

03-14 20:06:26.699 30995-30995/com.josh.testapp D/Message: Success

I'm not sure what it is I'm missing. The users should be coming back as a list containing user information, in this case just the information of the user logging in. But in other parts, this will display sub-users information as well which is why it is in List form in the first place.

Please help or guide me in the right direction.

login.java (where the call is made)

```
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(RestInterface.url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();


        RestInterface restInterface = retrofit.create(RestInterface.class);

        Call<userlogin> call = restInterface.Login(
                username.getText().toString(),                            // username
                pass.getText().toString()                                 // password
        );

        call.enqueue(new Callback<userlogin>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<userlogin> call, retrofit2.Response<userlogin> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    userlogin ul = response.body();

                    try{
                        String res = new Gson().toJson(response.body());
                        Log.d("Response", res);
                        System.out.println("Users:: " + ul.getUsers().toString());
                        Log.d("Message", ul.getMessage().toString());

                        List<users> userList = ul.getUsers();

                        for(int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++){
                            Log.d("Users", userList.get(i).getUsername());
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e){
                        Log.d("exception", e.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("unSuccessful", response.message());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<userlogin> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("onFailure", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your log says the application didn't receive the users list. You should check the server API

Comment: That's why I rely on the "message" part of the json for the success. My php code only shows success if able to log in and get the information. I have tested using Postman and get results and intended.

Answer (score 0):

After AbdulAli pointed out that it appeared to not be receiving the users list I decided to look over my code and run a few more tests on the server API. I discovered there was an issue with sessions. They weren't picking up and therefor returned a "Successful" yet empty user list. After implementing some CookieJar functions in I was able to pass my cookie for sessions and the user list was no longer empty.

While I feel like an idiot for missing something so obvious, I am very grateful for you pointing that out AbdulAli.